# how to refresh same url image and also preserve caching?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I found most solutions are adding "?+time()" after the image link to force browser download image every time, however, this seems not an ideal solution if no real change on image.

Could the **ifModified** in .ajax give a help?

Any ideas are welcome, thank you!

---

Edit:

Is there any ways without appending "?+..." to the image ink?

And consider the image may be remote resource.

Comment: 1. If image is remote resource, you have no control whatsoever over it.
2. If it is local resource, refer to my answer, which I'm improving. I added one answer (alternative).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ideal would be, that you append file modification time (on the server) or the ** PHP filemtime()** timestamp. This way, only when you change image on the server, the timestamp changes and **all users immediately** (on next load) get new version of the image.

But you have to use server-side language, like PHP. Google "filemtime()" for more info.

Representative xample:

```
<img src="image.png?<?php echo filemtime('image.png');?>" />
```

or:

```
<?php
echo '<img src="image.png?'.filemtime('image.png').'" />';
?>
```

You can also write a function to do that for you:

```
function image($file) {
   return $file.'?'.filemtime($file);
}
echo '<img src="'.image('image.png').'" />';
```

Comment: Thanks, your idea is good (+1). Perhaps for remote image, I can use stream_get_meta_data to get remote file **last modified** and append to the image.

Comment: Generally: If image is remote resource, you have no control whatsoever over it. But you can try, of course :) Also look at my 2nd answer.

Comment: @Code Keeper: Of course, great idea, but not all sites set the Last-Modified header. So you might end without the data.

Answer (score 1):

You could add the timestamp and filesize (in combination) of the image as query string (the thing after the quesionmark)

Basically any metadata of the file can be used for that, also seen md5() implementations, but I am not sure how good this scales.

This is an easy way without a database.

Comment: +1 on the md5(), I guest I have to compare which path is better between md5 and last modified time. Thank you.

Comment: Of course last modified time - md5 hashing every time will bring your server to the knees :D You have to mind the server resources, too.

Answer (score 0):

There is also another solution:

You can also set Expires header one year in future, like this:

Expires: Thu, 15 Sep 2011 20:00:00 GMT

This means browser will try to cache the image for one year, before requesting it from server again. But that can be bad, if you change the image in that time. Then user will have to do hard refresh (Control+F5) to force refresh. Stay with my 1st solution, or even beter, use both.

Comment: Thanks for the answer again. Those images update any time, and they are large size, so the solution is not flexible for me. Actually, I am using ajax to modify the <div /> content and giving a <img/> for it. If the <img/> src name remain unchanged, the browser doesn't even HEAD the same image again, and I am also saving one more http request. And this also give me a problem when the images are updated. Maybe appending "?+..." is the less dependency way to go.

Comment: The broweser doesn't HEAD ever. And this is making it extremly hard for us, developers. If you are using ajax, you can make call with ajax to get last modified time to refresh if necessary.